# How can I send bitcoins to my coinbase.com account for conversion to USD?

Tags: coinbase.com

First, I am not a merchant and I don't really care to become one (for now.)  Recently, I sent some BTC to Mt.Gox, sold them and then conveniently found out that I now have no way of withdrawing my USD to my bank account from gox.

After a bit of research, everyone is suggesting that I sell my BTC on Coinbase and then withdraw directly to my bank account.  My problem is that I can't find an easy way to deposit into my coinbase account that I just created and verified.

Is this an easy process that I've overlooked or will I need to setup a shell, merchant payment system and send myself my one-off BTC payment so that I can sell my bitcoins for USD?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I actually had this same issue today.

You can find your BTC deposit addresses on coinbase.com under...

Account Settings / Integrations tab / Bitcoin Addresses (scroll to bottom)

Here you can add new addresses as well as "view all"

I hope this helps!  :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  Wow, coinbase could certainly use a redesign of their account information to make this a bit more obvious.

Comment: doesn't work any more..

Answer (score 3):

To deposit coins to your Coinbase account, using the Coinbase website click Request money.  Leave the e-mail address blank and click the Request Money button.  It will then display a Bitcoin address and QR code.  Copy the Bitcoin address and then paste it as the withdrawal address from Mt. Gox.

But that's just how to move them there.

As far as automatically selling the coins, that's specifically limited to their merchant payment methods.  There's a configuration setting to tell Coinbase to automatically convert bitcoins you receive using a merchant payment method to dollars and send the dollars once-a0day to your bank.

- https://coinbase.com/merchant_settings

To get a Bitcoin address for a merchant payment method, you can simply send yourself a Payment invoice and use that Bitcoin address (multiple times if you wish) for receiving bitcoins which will then get cashed out to fiat immediately.

- https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/email_invoices

Answer (score 1):

With the new Coinbase design, these are the steps to follow in order to get your current BitCoin addresses or to generate new addresses. Note that you do not have the ability to remove addresses from you wallet, because if you did, future money sent to those addresses would be lost. This is a good thing for you.

1. Log in to Coinbase.
2. In the menus on the lefthand side of the page, under Wallet, select Account Settings.
3. The righthand side of the page will change / update. Notice at the top of that section, there are the following links: Account Settings, Bitcoin Addresses, and Apps.
4. Click Bitcoin Addresses and you'll be able to create new addresses and view your current addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add money with a debit card to Coinbase but you will need a bank account for withdrawal.