# My Bither Hot Wallet

Tags: exchanges, coinbase.com, bither

Purchased a Bither bitcoin machine and can't figure out how to work it.  I keep getting bitcoins but don't know how to send them to my Coinbase wallet and therefore exchange them for cash.  Help

Answer (score 1):

It is so easy to use [Bither](http://bither.net) app.

#### Generating Coinbase bitcoin receiving Address

first of all you need to check your Coinbase bitcoin receiving wallet address which is shown by a QR-code (you can find out how, from [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/how-can-i-send-bitcoins-to-my-coinbase-com-account-for-conversion-to-usd)).

#### Sending fund

Then you should try scanning that QR-code by your Bither app. for doing it, you need to choose one of your wallet (from the middle menu which is indicated by a big B and showing total amount of your funds) then you should choose the preferred wallet. then use the send icon and scan QR code and type the amount go ahead and send funds.

#### caution

by the way, you should be aware of your transaction fees. Bither does not propose any offer automatically; so you should choose your own policy for transaction fee by monitoring [mempool](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions) to get informed use [this website](https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#1,24h) to see which tx takes how long to get confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Bither is simple to use, you can either copy your coinbase address and paste in your Bither wallet or use the scan QR code function. Then imput the amount and send. 3 more things you shall know:

1. Bither also support segwit address.
2. Bither can use to create a cold wallet when you set up in a phone without any sim card or internet connection.
3. You can use Bither hot to monitor Bither cold, you can find the function by click the 'gear' button above.